# Rails Populating SELECT options from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I feel like this is basic but can't find details anywhere.

I have a basic application created by generating scaffold.

There is form already built into this that enters data. I have a SELECT (drop down) box in the form. I would like to be able to have the OPTIONS in this select box be pulled from a database.  Ideally, the end user would be able to add and edit these options.

I have no idea how to link that SELECT field in my form to where the OPTIONS will be STORED.

Can someone point me in the right direction as far as terminology as what to research? I'm coming up blank. I feel like this must be a common thing to do..

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Comment: Thanks - This seems to help with modifying the SELECT field manually, which I know how to do. But how do I tell the SELECT field to look for the options from a database?

Comment: Would this have anything to do with it?     options_from_collection_for_select(@people, 'id', 'name')

Comment: These helpers turn collections into select options, but the collections are presumed to come from the database. So if for example you have a `Country` model and you want to populate a dropdown with label/value pairs of the country's name and id, then you'd do something like `@countries = Country.all` in the controller and turn the `@countries` collection into select options in the view or presenter or whatever with one of these helpers.

Comment: So, pardon my phrasing, but would a separate Model have a separate database? I read about MVC but still a little unclear. I'm guessing the OPTIONS need to be stored in their own Model, correct?

Comment: I don't know enough about your use case. An ActiveRecord model typically corresponds to one table in a database. The conventional use of these helpers constructs select options out of a model that is assumed to do other interesting things besides just populate a select dropdown. But if for some reason you just wanted to save label/value pairs for a select menu, you could do that with a `SelectOption` model with `:label` and `:value` attributes (i.e., database columns). But I think you really need to get the fundamentals of ActiveRecord down before pursuing this further.

Answer (score 20):

As ByScripts' link includes, here is the script that worked for me (for those where time is not a luxury):

```
<%= collection_select(:lang_id, 0, Language.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Where `Language` is a table with one column called 'name' and an auto-assigned column id; `:lang_id` is the name of the element and `0` is the default selected index when the page loads.

Comment: This is on section 3.3, "3.3 Option Tags from a Collection of Arbitrary Objects" of this link. It helps to understand some variations, like in the case you want it in a form.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#option-tags-from-a-collection-of-arbitrary-objects